# BranchCache on separate Active Directory forest

Tags: branchcache

I have two sites running separate active directory forest.

In Philippines :
 
- Windows 2016 File Server as host / Shared folders are encrypted with Symantec Endpoint Encryption

In Taiwan:
 
- Windows 10 Pro in VDI (*can have Symantec Endpoint Encryption client*)

Scenario:

- I want to implement BranchCache on PH File Server and...
- Implement Distributed Cache Mode running on TW VDI PCs

Questions are:

- Can BranchCache work across separate active directory forests?
- If yes, what are the network ports do I need to allow between PH and TW
- What does it mean to say that **only** BranchCache BITS functionality is working with Pro editions of Windows?

Comment: Are the VDI instances persistent or non-persistent?

Comment: VDI instances are persistent